# Why does it be changed the order when I use the System.err.print?

Tags: java, system

```
package wrapper;

public class IntegerEqualExam {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i1 = new Integer(100);
        Integer i2 = new Integer(100);
        Integer i3 = new Integer(200);
        Integer i4 = new Integer("100");

        System.out.println("i1.equals(i2) = " + i1.equals(i2));
        System.out.println("i1.equals(i3) = " + i1.equals(i3));
        System.out.println("i1.equals(i4) = " + i1.equals(i4));


        if(i1 == i2)
            System.out.println("same reference");
        else
            System.out.println("different reference");

        System.err.println("error");
    }
}
```

I was just practicing Integer class, I found the System.err.println method by accident.

But I had some problem to understand this situation.

Whenever I run the this program, Result is changed.

Why did it happen?

Comment: Please dont show program code as a picture. It's very hard to understand what is happening then, since people usually want to copy the code and test the problem themselves. So please remove the pictures and paste your sourcecode.

Comment: Because the output of ``out`` and ``err`` is buffered in two different streams that get flushed to your console in an arbitrary order.

Comment: Use `StringBuilder`, not `StringBuffer`.